# Why does django keep telling me the app label doesn't exist when I use apps.get_model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following function...

```
def DoStuffWithModelInstance(model_instance):
    name = model_instance.name
    model = apps.get_model(name, name)
```

Where model_instance is a parameter I am passing in that holds two values, name and description.

The name value is the name of another Model. When I use

```
apps.get_model(name, name)
```

I get an error saying that the app_label does not exist....

However, if I type out the app_label like soo....

```
apps.get_model('some_app_label', name)
```

It works... 
How can I make it so I can pass in the app_label with a variable?

Comment: The app label should be something like `'polls'`, which is different from the model name, e.g. `'Question'`. So it's not clear why you think `get_model(name, name)` should work.

Comment: They are named the same (both the app label and model name).

Comment: You have to provide more information than that. At least more code than just one line and perhaps the traceback as well.

Comment: Not sure what more information I could provide... That's all there is to it Ive given everything that is relevant to the issue.... Passing a variable as the first parameter in apps.get_model produces that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there was hidden characters being sent to the variable. Specifically, a new line character '\n'.